# Attempting to store a null list item into a dictionary

Tags: c#, .net

If I take:

```
Dictionary<int,string> mydictionary = MyList.Where(x=> x.id == myid).ToDictionary(x => x.id, x=> x.string);
```

and the list Where does not return any values (none found matching those parameters), what happens to my dictionary?

I ask because I can't check `if (mydictionary==null)` as `mydictionary` cannot be `null`.

I'm sure you're asking "Well why don't you test it yourself?", but I don't currently have access to my development environment.

Comment: Then why not wait till you do have access and try it?

Comment: @TyrionLannister I'm very forgetful and if I don't ask right away then the idea will slip out of my head. At best I can read an answer, at worst I just get downvoted and I can re-look at my question later.

Comment: This will also fail if your list has duplicate ids equal to myid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The result is a `Dictionary<int, string>` instance with `Count == 0`, i.e., the same as

```
Dictionary<int, string> mydictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>();
```

Answer (score 1):

You will get empty(with no `KeyValuePair`) `Dictionary<int,string>` object.
`ToDictionary` extension method creates new `Dictionary` object and Adds elements.